# Openlayers 7.1.0: map not updating after adding/removing features

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm making a simple function to select features by polygon in Openlayers.
The following code is not the complete code but the most important parts.

This is the code for defining my layers

```
let Assetlayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: new VectorSource(),
  style: new Style({
    image: new Circle({
        radius: 7,
        fill: new Fill({ color: '#ffcc33' }),
        stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'black', width: 1 })
    })
  }) 
});
map.addLayer(Assetlayer);

let SelectionLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: new VectorSource()
});
map.addLayer(SelectionLayer);

let AssetSelectedlayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: new VectorSource(),
  style: new Style({
      image: new Circle({
          radius: 10,
          fill: new Fill({ color: '#f542ec' }),
          stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'black', width: 1 })
      })
  }) 
});
map.addLayer(AssetSelectedlayer);
```

This is my function for making a selection using a polygon

```
btnSelectByPolygon.addEventListener('click', () => {
drawInteraction = new Draw({
    source: SelectionLayer.getSource(),
    type: 'Polygon'
})
drawInteraction.on('drawend', (event) => {
    let poly = event.feature;
    let features = Assetlayer.getSource().getFeatures();

    features.forEach((feat) => {
        if poly.getGeometry().intersectsCoordinate(feat.getGeometry().getCoordinates())){
            console.log('Feature inside polygon')
            let clone = feat.clone();
            AssetSelectedlayer.getSource().addFeature(clone);
        }
    })
    SelectionLayer.getSource().clear();
    console.log(`Features in SelectionLayer: ${SelectionLayer.getSource().getFeatures().length}`)
    console.log(`Features in AssetSelectedlayer: ${AssetSelectedlayer.getSource().getFeatures().length}`)
    map.removeInteraction(drawInteraction)
})
map.addInteraction(drawInteraction);
```

})

So my goal is to draw a polygon in the SelectionLayer. I then check all features if they are inside that polygon. If inside polygon, add the feature to AssetSelectedlayer.

It seems the code works just fine but the map is not updating.
This is before selecting:
[image: Before Selecting]

After Selecting:

[image: After Selecting]

In the DevTools it show my polygon is removed from the SelectionLayer and the selected features are added to the AssetSelected. But the map is not updated and still showing the polygon and not showing the features added to AssetSelectedlayer.

When I close the polygon by double clicking, the map zooms in which is normal behaviour expect when drawing.

Why is this not working as expected?

Comment: The drawn feature is not added to the source until after the drawend event.  If you do not want to save it the interaction does not need a source.

Comment: To stop a final double click triggering a zoom set a 0 timeout before removing the interaction to make it asynchronous

Comment: it is actually very easy to disable the zoom on doubleclick on draw close. I just had to add 'stopClick: true' on th drawInteraction. Searching for hours and then i find it half an hour after posting a question :-S

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
btnSelectByPolygon.addEventListener('click', () => {
    drawInteraction = new Draw({
        type: 'Polygon'
    })
    drawInteraction.on('drawend', (event) => {
        let poly = event.feature;
        let features = Assetlayer.getSource().getFeatures();
    
        features.forEach((feat) => {
            if poly.getGeometry().intersectsCoordinate(feat.getGeometry().getCoordinates())){
                console.log('Feature inside polygon')
                let clone = feat.clone();
                AssetSelectedlayer.getSource().addFeature(clone);
            }
        })
        setTimeout(0, () =>
          map.removeInteraction(drawInteraction)
        );
    })
    map.addInteraction(drawInteraction);
})
```

Comment: That solves the polygon still being visible. Thanks for that. All I did was remove the source. But the biggest problem is the copied features not being visible. I gave the layer a style with a purple(-ish) color. But they are not visible. I want to make it clear to the user what their selection is. The visible features are the features in the AssetLayer (styled yellow)

Comment: It works as expected here https://codesandbox.io/s/webgl-points-layer-forked-4k2m6g?file=/main.js  Do you have a style set on the point features which will override the layers style?

Comment: Yesterday the project was getting on my nerves so i closed it. When I started it this morning, everything worked fine. No idea why since caching is disable when using DevTools but it works. But i thank you for you contribution by suggesting not using a source in de draw interaction